# What is Equivalent hash_hmac PHP on Visual Basic .Net

Tags: vb.net, hash

I'm rewriting hash_hmac code I got on PHP to VB.Net. 
I need same result generated both in PHP and VB.Net.

This is hash_hmac code on PHP:

```php
$data = urlencode('2019-07-21T15:30:57.465Z');
$data = '_ts='.$data;
$signatureSecretKey = "secrete";
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256',$data,$signatureSecretKey,true);
$signature = base64_encode($hash);
echo $signature;
```

The result shows:

```
upLQYFI3pI2m9Pu5fyiobpvCRhTvRmEyxrVDrdJOYG4=
```

And here is my code on VB:

```vb
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim _ts, data, signature, secrete, hash
        secrete = "secret"
        _ts = DateTime.Now.ToString("2019-07-21T15:30:57.465Z")
        data = "_ts=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_ts)
        signature = Encrypt(data, secrete)
        TextBox1.Text = signature
    End Sub

    Public Function Encrypt(Content As String, Secret As String) As String
        Dim kode As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim getkode As Byte() = kode.GetBytes(Secret)
        Dim cont As Byte() = kode.GetBytes(Content)
        Dim hmcKu As New HMACSHA256(getkode)
        Dim HashCode As Byte() = hmcKu.ComputeHash(cont)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)
    End Function
```

Result of my code is:

```
892q1ArPxIqrX48PQegliVql703V2fcipb5A08F053o=
```

You can see my VB code generates different result from PHP.
I have tried almost every method I got from internet but the result always different. So, what is equivalent hash_hmac of PHP on VB and what is the right way to make this same result?
Please help?

Comment: SO is not a place to ask questions of the form "how do I do X".  It's up to you to do the research and find out how to do X, then make an attempt to do it.  If that attempt doesn't work, then you can post here and provide the specifics of not only what you are trying to do but also how you tried to do it and what happened when you tried.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question, I actually have tried since 2 days ago. I have tried many times I got from internet but the result always different. I have updated my question. Thank for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
dim hmac as HMACSHA256 = new HMACSHA256(key) ' key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<secret>")
dim hashValue as byte() = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<message>"))
dim result as string = BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "").ToLower()
hmac.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution from fb community.
This is exact solution for this cases:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Shared DES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    Private Shared MD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim _ts, data, signature, secrete
        secrete = "secret"
        _ts = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss.fff\Z")
        data = "_ts=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_ts)
        Dim reg = New Regex("%[a-f0-9]{2}")
        data = reg.Replace(data, Function(m) m.Value.ToUpperInvariant())
        signature = Encrypt(data, secrete)
        TextBox1.Text = signature
    End Sub

    Public Function Encrypt(Content As String, Secret As String) As String
        Try
            Dim kode As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim getkode As Byte() = kode.GetBytes(Secret)
            Dim cont As Byte() = kode.GetBytes(Content)
            Dim hmcKu As New HMACSHA256(getkode)
            Dim HashCode As Byte() = hmcKu.ComputeHash(cont)
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```